# Port forward from external postgresql to localhost

Tags: port-forwarding, firewalld

I have several databases hosted outside the application server, ex:
DB instances:

```
192.168.178.21:5432
192.168.178.22:5432
192.168.178.23:5432
```

app-server: `192.168.178.11`

now I want to forward the external dbs to ports 5431-5433
and be able to connect with psql to localhost:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U <user> -d <db>
```

I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

services on this server are only allowed to connect to localhost, additionally these ports will be forwarded with ssh.

I tried firewalld masquerade:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-forward-port=port=5432:proto=tcp:toport=5432:toaddr=192.168.178.22 --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Any ideas? (I've cowered several manuals, including CentOS, Fedora and Redhat intros)

EDIT:
Only Postgres Ports are open on the respective servers, nothing else.
I will try using a postgresql aware gateway like [crunchy-proxy](https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how is the postgresql [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) configured and whether the postgresql server listen on IP addresses you've listed.

Otherwise If You can ssh to those servers You can use ssh port forwarding `-L` option in ssh(1)
example:

```
ssh user@192.168.178.21 -L 5431:localhost:5432 -f
ssh user@192.168.178.22 -L 5432:localhost:5432 -f
ssh user@192.168.178.23 -L 5433:localhost:5432 -f
```

You can achieve the same with following `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host db1
        Hostname 192.168.178.21
        LocalForward            localhost:5431 localhost:5432

Host db2
        Hostname 192.168.178.22
        LocalForward            localhost:5432 localhost:5432

Host db3
        Hostname 192.168.178.23
        LocalForward            localhost:5433 localhost:5432
```

and then just

```
ssh -f db1
ssh -f db2
ssh -f db3
```

Comment: Only Postgres Ports are open on the respective servers, nothing else. (For "security" reasons...).